# WPF C# - Make changes in registry at app startup for standard (non-privilege) user

Tags: c#, wpf, registry, uac

Below are steps I have tried to make work on my Windows desktop app.Where I need to write `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`. Which works fine for admin user but fails for standard user who has no rights to write in registry.

1) I have set `<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />` so that user has rights at time of installation.

And created script and run at time of Installation which fails to install the app due to this script.

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

Sub strLocalMachinePath1 = "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
objRegistry.OpenSubKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strLocalMachinePath1);

If objRegistry.GetValue("MyApp.exe") Is Nothing Then
    objRegistry.SetValue("MyApp.exe", 8000)
End If
If objRegistry.GetValue("MyApp.vshost.exe") Is Nothing Then
     objRegistry.SetValue("MyApp.vshost.exe", 11000)
End If

End Sub
```

2) I have tried `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` which asks for admin password everytime opening the app. Which fails for standard user who is not admin.

3) I have tried to write the same in `App.xml.cs` -> `App_Startup` ->

```
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
            key.CreateSubKey("FeatureControl");
           key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl", true);
            key.CreateSubKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
           key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
```

But makes no difference and starts error of `No Internet connection`

```
var client = new WebClientPool().GetIdleWebClientObject()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If user does not have permissions to write to certain registry entry - he cannot do that, whatever `requestedExecutionLevel` you specify for your application. When you specify something like `requireAdministrator` it just means on startup UAC prompt will be shown to run application with admin permissions, but if user is not admin - that won't help.

However in this case you don't need that, because instead of writing to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` you can write `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` part of registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Comment: I have already tried that, please check 3rd point of question. In this case, its not allowing me to connect internet, once I relaunch app. Any workaround on this?

Comment: @Heena how is internet connection related here at all?

Comment: I am not sure why. But I have used Internet checking code after that in On_Startup. Like this
`using (var client = new  WebClient GetIdleWebClientObject())
                {
                    using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }`

Comment: Your solution is working fine for me. In case of standard user.